# needs tips creating JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on this code to create a table which lights up a different cell at at a time I have managed to create a javascript function to do this but all the cells are lighting up at the same time. I want help so that one cell lights up at a time and then resets to original colour

here is sample code

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change(){
            document.getElementById("myTable").rows[1].cells[1].style.backgroundColor ="yellow";
            document.getElementById("myTable").rows[2].cells[2].style.backgroundColor ="green";
            document.getElementById("myTable").rows[2].cells[0].style.backgroundColor ="blue";
            document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[3].style.backgroundColor ="red";
            document.getElementById("myTable").rows[3].cells[1].style.backgroundColor ="orange";
        }

        function reset () {
            rows[1].cells[1].Value = ""
            rows[1].cells[1].Value = ""
            rows[1].cells[1].Value = ""
            rows[1].cells[1].Value = ""
            i = 0
        }   
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h2 style="text-align:center-left"> Sky Apprenticeship Test</h2>
    <table id="myTable"  width="80%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Run Program" onclick="change();" />

        <input type="button" value="Reset" onClick="this.table.reset()" />

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look into the Math.random function to get a two random numbers, row and cell.  Then use setInterval to call this function so that it will run on the interval you set.  Add comment if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to paint the cells sometime after with a timer. The browser will repaint all your changes if you do them all before the next repaint. You'll want to do the change in an interval visible to human sight. There's no point doing one change for each repaint if the browser repaints at 3 ms or something like that.

```js
var speed = 1000,
    resetSpeed = 500;

document.getElementById('clickMe').addEventListener('click', change);
document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', function() {
  reset(document.getElementById('myTable'));
});

function change() {
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(changeColorAndReset.bind(null, 'myTable', 'green', 2, 2))
    .then(changeColorAndReset.bind(null, 'myTable', 'blue', 2, 0))
    .then(changeColorAndReset.bind(null, 'myTable', 'red', 0, 3))
    .then(changeColorAndReset.bind(null, 'myTable', 'orange', 3, 1))
}

function reset(table) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(table.rows, function(row) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(row.cells, function(cell) {
      cell.style.background = '';
    });
  });
}

function changeColor(table, color, x, y) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(table).rows[x].cells[y].style.backgroundColor = color;
        resolve();
      }, speed);
    });
}

function changeColorAndReset(table, color, x, y) {
  return changeColor(table, color, x, y).then(function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(table).rows[x].cells[y].style.backgroundColor = '';
        resolve();
      }, resetSpeed);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2 style="text-align:center-left"> my project</h2>
  <table id="myTable" width="80%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Run Program">
    <input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset" />
```

It probably is better to use queues (not easy to stop the animation) instead of promises but this is just an example.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help I have created the JavaScript so that it runs when the web page loads up however i want the function to reset before the next function runs i.e. one cells lights up and then resets then the next cell lights up

Comment: @STurk, just keep working on the promise. You might as well use an animation library. Either jQuery or velocity could work.